# Unable to update text string in Mysql using PHP::PDO

Tags: php, mysql

I have done it a million times before and never failed, but this time I am making some mistake and can't figure out.

I am doing

```
$sql = 'update user set token=:token and token_time=:token_time where id=:id';
$query = $con->prepare($sql);
$query->bindValue(':token',$token,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(':token_time',$current_datetime,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(':id',$id,PDO::PARAM_INT);

if($query->execute())
{
    var_dump($token);
    var_dump($id);
    var_dump($current_datetime);
}
```

and I am getting the dump as follows

```
string(32) "a10b15b88ed35551a17cbdf4e5db2624" int(1) string(19) "2015-03-09 15:50:18"
```

which means the fields are not null, query executed and I also checked, there is a row with id=1 in the table `user`.

But when I look into the table, the row with id=1 is not updated. why?

**EDIT**

MySQL table

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| fname      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lname      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| email      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| password   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| contact    | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| token      | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| reg_time   | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| token_time | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**EDIT**

As per @davidstrachan, the problem is in the `update` query. `,` should be used instead of `and`, and then it works fine.

Now the new question is why didn't MySQL give error?

Comment: The bound parameter uses $current_datetime but your are var_dump()ing $token_time??

Comment: @RamRaider : Sorry that was copied before execution, made the correction.

Comment: Wrong Update syntax Try
`'update user set token=:token,token_time=:token_time where id=:id';`

Comment: This thread's answer says you must use double quotes, so $id is interpolated.


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129547/updating-data-with-php-pdo

Comment: @davidstrachan : `and` is allowed in MySQL. I checked by executing the query manually.

Comment: @davidstrachan : Wait . I guess you are right. Mysql says `Matched : 1` `changed:0` if I use `and`. Why didn't MySQL give error?

Comment: Try adding a `$arr = $query->errorInfo(); print_r($arr);` after the `$query->execute()` Just to be sure there are no errors.

Comment: And maybe MySQL didn't give error because log level is too low.